# Create bridge (eth0-wlan0) using my laptop

Tags: linux, networking, bridging

Okay. I might be asking this again but none of the answers solved my problem.

I have a PC A which has eth0 (192.168.1.28/24) connected to another machine B's eth1 (192.168.1.11/24). A has another interface wlan0 which has dynamic IP and is connected to internet (but eth0 is not).

So the setup looks something like

```
              ---------------------------------         ----------
Internet ---- | wlan0 | A (my machine) | eth0 | ------ | eth1 | B |
              ---------------------------------         ----------
```

I want to access internet from eth1 of B. I can ping eth0 IP of A from B but not wlan0 IP.

I tried to masquarade eth0 but it did not work.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I did this in Ubuntu, only the other way round. I was in a building with an ethernet connection, but no WiFi and my wife had an iPad. It was very simple to create my own WiFi network using the laptop, and the reverse configuration seems equally straightforward, though I haven't done it this way round. Create a new network connection of type **Ethernet**, and under IPv4 settings select **Shared to other computers**.

Comment: i did it once in windows 7 but no idea in linux, anyhow, you should specify your linux distro

Comment: Provide the exact commands that you used, otherwise it is difficult to determine what you did wrong. Did you enable `ip_forward`?